# File upload contraint for archieving single tar.gz to AWS Glacier or S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-glacier

I have single 50GB zip file and doesn't plan to retrieve it at least for a year or two. Main issue is I have almost run out of Disk space 95% at my EC2 Instance (expanding isn't option) & due to space constraint breaking into chunks for multi-part upload isn't an option.

- Hence what's is the best recommendation for storing this single file and best option to upload to either AWS S3 or Glacier?
- Any suggestion for 3rd party tool S3 or Glacier.
- Read the article that Glacier make sense for > 500GB or 1 TB archiving and it's the frequency of transfer cost which matters. Cost matters but has 2nd priority.
- I thought just copying to file directly to bucket and use life cycle policy to archive to Glacier. Is it a good option ?

  **aws s3 cp <50gbfile> s3-bucket-name**

Appreciate your help, thank you

Comment: Why not directly upload to glacier ?

Comment: there is a size limit of 4 GB for uploading. My file is single zip file with 50 GB, that's the constraint.

Answer (score 0):

You can do so with S3 Lifecycle to Glacier or Glacier Deep Archive https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-transition-general-considerations.html

- breaking into chunks for multi-part upload: you can actually spin up a temporary EC2 to run the job or use lambda, multi-part upload has SDK with 4GB chunks. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_UploadPart.html